# Delay Between End of Root Task and Start of Dependent Task

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm using a series of streams and tasks to extract, load, and transform raw data from our ERP system to Snowflake. I'm noticing a 2+ minute delay between when the root task completes and when the next dependent task starts. Each task calls an SQL stored procedure and completes in less than 5 seconds, so I though everything would complete in under a minute. There are a few other queries running at the same time, but they all complete in less than 5 seconds too and nothing that would explain such a long delay. Warehouse usage doesn't indicate being overloaded. Here's the sequence:

- **Task 1** runs every 5 minutes using `COPY INTO` to move files from internal table stage to raw
  data table.
- **Stream 1** records inserts only on the raw data table.
- **Task 2** depends on Task 1 using `MERGE INTO` to transform and move records from stream 1 to the current data table.
- **Stream 2** records inserts / updates / deletes on the current data table.
- **Task 3** depends on Task 2 using `MERGE INTO` to move records from stream 2 to the historical data table.

Here's a copy of the activity log from Snowflake:

| Task | Start Time | End Time | Duration |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4:29 PM | 4:29 PM | 1.9 seconds |
| 2 | 4:31 PM | 4:31 PM | 2.7 seconds |
| 3 | 4:33 PM | 4:33 PM | 3.0 seconds |

Any ideas what could be causing this delay? Or have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 0):

Has this issue started recently? Can you open a Support Case to debug this, as this might need engineering engagement to debug.

Thanks.

Comment: It's been happening since being put into production. I've reached out to my Snowflake account manager to get their input. I'll create a case and see what they find out.

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake engineering looked into it and said this is behavior is expected due to being on a shared cluster. The current alternative is switching to a dedicated virtual warehouse. Here's the full response from Snowflake:

> Engineering investigated the issue and after looking into this issue they updated that this ~1-minute delay is expected due to shared cluster as per our internal architecture. The engineering team is already doing some ongoing work to improve the throughput and reduce latency for customers but those work won’t land soon. Thus currently, if you need to mitigate this issue you could switch to a dedicated cluster.